# Error links css using Assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have a layout that is used by several bundles so I put the css files in **web/dashboard /css/**.

When I use the simple method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

the style is applied and I get this HTML Code in source code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/boutique/web/dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

But when I use **Assetic**

```
{% stylesheets 'dashboard/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I have many errors in the style and I have this code HTML in source code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/boutique/web/app_dev.php/css/ac0081b_part_1_ace-fonts_1.css" />
```

and in mod **prod** the style does not work and I have the HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/boutique/web/css/ac0081b.css" />
```

As I said , css files are in **web/dashboard /css/**

Answer (score 0):

> and in mod prod the style does not work and I have the HTML code

Are you sure you deployed the Assets ?

```
// install the assets calling
app/console assets:install --env=prod

// dump your assets to real files
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

> I have many errors in the style and I have this code HTML in source code

I think the code you are seeing is the way that [assetic works](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).